# Calling methods from the view controller from any class in the project

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm a beginner with Objective C and iPhone development.

It's there any way to call methods from the view controller from any class in my project ?

I began writting a small openGL game, beginning from the EAGLview generated by the default opengl project that Xcode allows me to create. The game so far works well, but I would like to call methods from the ViewController from my game class, for example, call some methods which use the GameKit framework that I wrote in my ViewController.

It's there any way to make It happen ?, or I'm doing it wrong and there is a different aproach which I should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

1) Pass in a pointer down your chain of objects and views so that you can pass it messages in the controller
2) Setup a global variable that points to the view controller
3) Consider extracting the relevant code in your view controller into another class, then using this class in both places.

I would lean towards 3 if I were you as it is cleanest and scaleable.

Comment: Thanks for Your help.

Just Another question..since I'm trying to use the GameKit framework, it's possible for me to use it from any class ?, all the examples I see declare methods to implemment the P2P funcionality inside an UIViewController ?, such as GameControler: : UIViewController <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate, GKSessionDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>  ...thanks !

Comment: You can pull logic out where ever you want.  It is really beyond the scope of this question though...